# How can I get this to not read an arduino digital input?

Tags: arduino, c, input, toggle-switch

I have been working on this for a while.  It is a small part of a much bigger code.

I have a digital input pin connected to a on/off switch and another input pin connected to a momentary push button. For the momentary push button I am using the onebutton library. It works great.

I am trying to make it so the momentary push button does nothing unless the on off switch connected to a digital pin if switched on or HIGH. For some reason the momentary push button still gets read and my program runs regardless of whether the switch is swichted or not.

```
void loop()
{
    ignition_mode = digitalRead(ignition);
    if (ignition_mode == HIGH);
    {
        button.tick();
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (ignition_mode == HIGH);` does nothing, because `;` is an empty statement performed if the condition is true.

Comment: at least one `}` is missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you format you code properly, you can see that it does not what you intended:

```
void loop()
{
  ignition_mode = digitalRead(ignition);
  if (ignition_mode == HIGH)
    ;  // empty statement which means that nothing is done if the condition is true
  { // new scope-block, which has quite no effect here
    button.tick();
  }
}
```

You most likely intended:

```
void loop()
{
  ignition_mode = digitalRead(ignition);
  if (ignition_mode == HIGH)
  { 
    button.tick();
  }
}
```

Comment: sweet, does the IDE platform used to compile this code not include even *basic* warnings about suspicious code?

Answer (score 3):

Two possibilities:

Remove the ";" after the if. The correct version would be:

```
if (ignition_mode) {
 .. Do something here
}
```

Have you checked that the level on that pin actually toggles or is it fixed to some value?